# A question about implementation of Farkas lemma

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, linear-programming, matlab, duality-theorems

> **The Farkas Lemma**: Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix, $b\in\mathcal{R}^m$. Then exactly one of the following two assertions is true: 
> (1) There exists an $x\in \mathcal{R}^n$ such that $Ax=b$ and $x\ge0$. 
> (2) There exists a $y\in \mathcal{R}^m$ such that $A^Ty\ge0$ and $b^Ty<0$.

I want to check which assertion is true for a given $b$. So I constructed the linear programming problem according to the second statement:
\begin{equation}
\min b^Ty\\
s.t. -A^Ty\le0
\end{equation}
The idea is simple. if the solution $b^Ty$ is great than or equal to $0$, then the first assertion is true; otherwise the second one is true.

But the following matlab implementation always gives me the result $y=0$ or "the problem is unbounded". Something is wrong, but i have no idea. I would be thankful for any help or references.

```
m = 2;
n = 4;
A = rand(m,n);
b = rand(m,1);
f = b;
A = -A';
y = linprog(f,A,zeros(n,1),[],[],[],[]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you found a $y$ such that $-A^Ty \le 0$ and $b^Ty < 0$. Notice that $ky$, where $k$ is positive, would also be feasible and hence we can scale $y$ to arbitary large magnitude, hence $\min b^Ty$ doesn't exists and it can go to $-\infty$, it is unbounded.

You might like to impose the constraint $b^Ty \ge -1$ so that you do not get the unbounded message.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, and the problem is solved. The code would give the result either $-1$ or $0$ after imposing the constraint $b^Ty\ge-1$. The reason for obtaining $y=0$ is the same. Suppose there exists a $y$ such that $-A^Ty\le0$ and $b^Ty\ge0$, then $y$ can be scaled to $0$ for the minimization. A further question is that is it possible to impose a linear constraint to the norm of $y$ since we care more about the angle between $b$ and $y$?

Comment: if you impose $-1 \le y_i \le 1$, then it is promised that $\|y\|_2 \le \sqrt{n}$.

Comment: The imposing of $-1\le y_i \le 1$ seems not working, since i want to prevent $ \| y \|_2$ from being $0$

Comment: you mean you want $y$ to be non-zero?Do you know any additional information about $b$? If $b$ is positive and $b^Ty \ge 0$, then $y=0$ is the optimal solution.  I think you have another completely different question on your mind?